# How do I save a point cloud snapshot/data from the Velodyne VLP-16, using terminal only?

Tags: ssh, terminal, ros, point-clouds, lidar

I have a Velodyne VLP-16 set up with which I communicate through SSH, meaning I only have the terminal to communicate. The VLP-16 is attached to a remote ubuntu 18.04. How can I still execute point cloud services and extract point cloud files (pcap,pcd)?

I don't know which files to navigate to and execute to save a point cloud image.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What have you tried that doesn't work?